# HTML table - making a single column responsive

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

How do I go about making the 'description' column responsive? As you can see the bootstrap description is pushing my site. I would like the description go for a specific width, and the text to go behind the 'language' and have just **one horizontal scroll bar for all of the description column.**
[image]

I'm using bootstrap btw so the code doesn't contain a css but maybe it helps you anyway :)

```
       <div className="table-responsive-lg">
          <table className="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Description</th>
                  <th scope="col">Language</th>
                  <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                  <th scope="col">File Size (kb)</th>
                  <th scope="col">Open Issues</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>{data.map(item => (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td><a href={item.html_url}>{item.name}</a></td>
                  <td>{item.description}</td>
                  <td>{item.language}</td>
                  <td>{item.created_at.slice(0,10)}</td>
                  <td>{item.size}</td>
                  <td>{item.open_issues}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}</tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a class with some CSS as below:

```css
.fixed-width {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

then add class `fixed-width` to all `<th>` and `<td>` tags in your "description" column.

Comment: It works! :) but I was looking for 1 single horizontal bar in the whole description column, what you suggested gave me a horizontal scroll bar for each <td> so I modified it to `overflow-x:auto;` but still gave me individual horizontal bars for each overflowing <td> do you perhaps know a way around?

Comment: @helpmeplease I think there's no way to do that using only pure CSS. Here I wrote an example using `rowspan`: https://jsfiddle.net/nq0g1z3f/1/ (you will need to add some CSS to make the `div` tags look like `td`). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS.

```
.table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width:310px;}
.table td {width:100px; /*add as per your requirements*/ word-wrap:break-word;}
```

Using Child Pseudo Or Unique Id OR Class.
Set as per screen required. Using @media.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the previous answer a bit and add the `.fixed-width` class only on the column containing the description

```css
.fixed-width {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
}
```

```html
  <div className="table-responsive-lg">
          <table className="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Description</th>
                  <th scope="col">Language</th>
                  <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                  <th scope="col">File Size (kb)</th>
                  <th scope="col">Open Issues</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr key="1">
                  <td><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></td>
                  <td  class="fixed-width">some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong description here</td>
                  <td>English</td>
                  <td>19/01/2021</td>
                  <td>38</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your css Like this:

```
tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 245px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width: 245px;
}
```